# max and count on joing n to n tables

Tags: mysql, hive

I'm blocked with a query and I'm needing some help.
If someone could help me I'd appreciate a lot :)

I have two tables (I'm using only one movie for showing the situation):

**Table Consumption**

```
client_id   movie_id    name        date_consumption
XXX         1           MovieA          01/Jan/2000
YYY         1           MovieA          01/Jan/2000
ZZZ         1           MovieA          02/Jan/2000
XXX         1           MovieA          02/Jan/2000
ZZZ         1           MovieA          10/Jan/2000
```

**Table movies_owners**

```
movie_id    rightowner      date_buyed*
A           LucasFilm       01/Jan/2000
A           Disney          02/Jan/2000
A           Sony            05/Jan/2000
```

**Date_buyed : It's the date where the movie belongs to a new right owner.*

**The ideia is simple**:

> I have to find the count of clients who watched a movie for day with
>   the correct Right Owner in the day this movie was watched.

**Table Expected**

```
movie_id    date_consumption    rightowner      consumption(count)
MovieA      01/Jan/2000         LucasFilm       2
MovieA          02/Jan/2000         Disney          2
MovieA          10/Jan/2000         Sony            1
```

--

With this query I can find the correct right owner of the movie in some day (max of all buyed dates before the day in question):

```
SELECT A.movie_id, A.date_buyed, A.rightowner
    FROM movies_owners A
    WHERE A.date_buyed EXISTS (
        SELECT max(date_buyed) 
        FROM movies_owners
        WHERE TO_DATE(date_buyed) <= TO_DATE('2000-01-02') AND movie_id = 'MovieA') 
    AND movie_id = 'MovieA';
```

But my problem is when joing with the consumption table.
I can't use the date_consumption from table consumption in a sub query.

I tried to break into a auxiliar table for doing the join, but I still can't find the result. =\

Can someone has, at least, an ideia or suggestion for me please?
Thank you all in advanced.

*Juste for info: I'm working with Hive, but the sintax is almost the same from Sql.*

Comment: The moviw_id has diferent values in Table Consumption than Table movies_owners

Comment: Indeed. Cause the field date_buyed (which it's the date where the movie belongs to a new right owner) is not the same as date_consumption from the other table

Comment: In one table movie_Id is 'MovieA' and in second it is 'A'. Should MovieA to be parsed to match 'A' in the join?

Comment: Is it only one owner possible on one date?

Comment: My mistake.. fixed that one.. it's the same reference for the movies. And yes, only one right owner for consumption date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive does not support non-equijoins. Move join on `c.consumption_date<=o.date_buyed` condition to the WHERE clause:

```
select c.movie_id, c.date_consumption, o.rightowner, c.consumption_count 
from
(--consumption count per movie, date
 select substr(movie_id,6) movie_id, date_consumption, count(*) consumption_count 
   from consumption
  group by  substr(movie_id,6), date_consumption
)c
left join movies_owners o on c.movie_id=o.movie_id
where c.consumption_date<=o.date_buyed
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I could solved the problem, but I had to break into two tables. I'm not able to do the max when having the rightowner in the same request, cause in this case, I have to group by by rightowner. So, I used two auxiliar tables!! Thank you !!